# Does Salesforce HTML Email tracking work with Salesforce for Outlook plugin?

Tags: email, outlook

I have some users who are using the HTML email tracking feature within Salesforce. They want to start using the Salesforce for Outlook plugin - but want to still be able to use the Email tracking in Salesforce.

From my tests, it looks like the plugin just creates a task and doesn't work with HTML Tracking. I have a user who swears it worked at his other company.

Anyone know if email tracking in Salesforce will work with the plugin? Is there a hack to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT : Saying all this, I just tried it, and, like you said,  it seems to attach the Email from outlook as an Activity, rather than an HTML Email, which I assume is the key to tracking. So unless there is a way to attach the Salesforce2Outlook email as HTML Email, its unlikely.

It is an idea, so surely not possible then

http://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrXvAAK

---

Most email tracking works by using a one pixel image, a link to which is embedded in the body of the email. This link is to an image stored as an externally available 'document' on your Salesforce org. So when the recipient opens the email, the link is accessed, which is used to track the email.

In theory if you were to insert this img link tag in your HTML email that you send from the Outlook Connector, it should still work as usual.

Here is a resource explaining how this works with templates 
http://www.shellblack.com/salesforce/sales-cloud/html-email/

However, it goes without saying that tracking is also dependent on the recipient's mail client not blocking out image content, which MS Outlook does (depending on security settings i presume).

Comment: Ya I've been messing around with the <img> tag I found in a sample email. It contains the org id and a parameter they list as "esid" with this ID: 0184000000MMjky  the ID changes for every email. So I'm assuming salesforce is creating some sort of record behind the scenes assigned to that ID and that's how it's doing the tracking.

So we can't hack it because we won't know what the esid should be

Comment: Thanks to Winter '13 new method id.getSObjectType() says the esid is type "EmailStatus"

Comment: That's cool. In the old world you could stick 018/o in the URL and it should show up if it has a tab ;)

Comment: Ya I tried that and it gave me insufficient permissions. Tisk Salesforce for not letting me hack you!

Comment: EmailStatus supports no querying or DML. No hacking ;/ Wonder if its worth exposing a resource via sites and then capturing the access event. Or Google Analytics ?

Comment: it's an interesting idea Techtrekker, but we just passed the limit of "too much time for something very simple" It was a request from Sales to be able to use Outlook + HTML email tracking. It's not a major initiative so we'll just say "Not possible now" and move on.